# how to center nav link using html, (No Css?)

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Is there away that i can use only html to center these nave links without having to do a css code?

nav link are align left, would want to bring them center of the webpage.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

[image: nav link are aligned left]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `.justify-content-center` to the `.nav` to center those nav links, since the `.nav` is already displayed as a flexbox:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
    ...
</ul>
...
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/g1fn7smr/2/